# How to set Java floatArray in jni field

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

in Java field

```
public class JNI{
    static{ System.loadLibrary("jni");}
    public float dataArray[] = new float[5];
    public float data;
}
```

in JNI c++ field

```
Java_example_JNI_setData(JNEEnv *env, jobject instance){
    jclass jclass1 = (*env).GetObjectClass(instance);
    jfieldID jfieldID1 = (*env).GetFieldID(jclass1, "data", "F");
    jfloat var1 = 1.0f;
    (*env).setFloatField(instance, jfieldID1, var1);
    float var[5] = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f, 5.f};
}
```

// how to set dataArray to var?
// or how to use "SetFloatArrayRegion" not return value.

Answer (score 0):

`float` is java primitive types and their machine-dependent native type is `jfloat`

So you need to map `float` as `jfloat` inside you java class, class which implemented native methods.

[More about JNI types and Data structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo013_PassArrayBack_passFloatArray
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jfloatArray array) {

  /* get size of the array */
  jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);

  /* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
  jfloat *body = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, array, 0);

  /* do some stuff */
  for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("Float value: %f\n", body[i]);

    /* update value */
    body[i] = 0;
  }

  /* release body when you decide it is no longer needed
    Do not pass changes back to Java */
  (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, array, body, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

More can be found here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-013/

As for accessing fields of object passed from Java to C you can find some info here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/